# Toast and android lifecycle

Tags: java, android

Sorry, but I can not find suitable information about where I can use `Toast`,
and how its usage depend on activities life cycle.

Can `Toast` be shown during `Application` object creation, before the first `Activity` was created?

Can it be used during `Activity.onCreate` if I have single Activity in my app?

Can it be used between `onPause` and `onResume`, when user switch from my single `Activity` to other application?

Answer (score 4):

Without being able to give you any sources on this except my own experience, the `Toast`, once shown, is not bound to any lifecycle at all. 
You can show it with any `Context` (application context or activity) and even from a service, it will not disappear should it's context finish.

Once shown, it will remain shown, until it's duration expires or you manually cancel it.

You do not have to mind any further lifecycle implications.

Comment: I think the toasts are bound to the application context, but not "to no context at all". Thus one shouldn't use the activity context, but the application one thanks to `getApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it everywhere you only need one context object

for example sometimes i use it for debug but sometimes they are so much that i must force close my app

Answer (score 1):

You can use them even outside the activity life cycle, but for that you need to pass ApplicationContext using getApplicationContext() and not Activity Content ActivityName.this, because ApplicationContext lives beyond the lifeCycle of the activity.